# What is the corresponding WPF .NET component to a JTable in Java Swing?

Tags: java, .net, wpf, swing, components

I have a small Java Swing application that I want to rewrite in WPF .NET.

The application uses a [`JTable`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) with an `AbstractTableModel` and a custom `TableCellRenderer`. I use my custom cell renderer to display the objects in two rows.

What is the corresponding WPF .NET component to JTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `JTable`, but I suppose either [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx) or [DataGrid](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-datagrid-feature-walkthrough.aspx) will do the trick.